# What is notation / sign for incomparable elements?

Tags: notation, order-theory

$a$ and $b$ belongs to partially ordered set.

$a < b$: means $a$ is less then $b$

What is the notation / sign to say: $a$ and $b$ incomparable (it is not the case that $a<b$ or $a>b$ or $a=b$)?

Comment: Fine would be $a<>b$.

Comment: I've seen $a\|b$ in cases like this. (I can't remember a reference though.)